# Using angelleye paypal with simplemvc framework

Tags: php, paypal

I have used composer to download the Angell EYE PayPal library into my vendor directory. Now I'm trying to call the class within a controller.

I've tried various methods:

```
Use \angelleye\PayPal;
```

at the top of page. I've tried using the `require()` method.

Within the controller I have used

```
$paypal = PayPal::PayPal($payment);
```

And a few other ways, but I just get the error `Class not found at line 179` and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to load a config file (depending on your framework) and the autoloader.

```
require_once('includes/config.php');
require_once('vendor/angelleye/paypal-php-library/autoload.php');
```

Of course, adjust the paths to suit where you have those saved, but the autoloader is what makes the classes available to you.

If you want more direct help you can [submit a ticket here](http://www.angelleye.com/support).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response.

I actually managed to get it working on the framework.

I did nt have to load anything or require the class as the composer autoload must do it for me in the framework.

I simply added :

```
$PayPal = new \angelleye\PayPal\PayPal($PayPalConfig);
```

and it started to work.

Im guessing if i want to use the PayFlow i would call using:

```
$PayPal = new \angelleye\PayPal\PayFlow($PayPalConfig);
```

I will definately post back if the rest of the proccess fails to work.